# Can't uderstand the reason appearing errors while date parse in pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, io

I'm just learning Python.
And the next code:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df_f = pd.read_csv("files/all.csv", header=1, names=["user_id", "name", "screen_name", "description",
                                            "verified", "location", "lat", "lon", "country",
                                            "created_at", "followers_count", "friends_count",
                                            "statuses_count", "favourites_count", "listed_count", "class"],
                                            parse_dates=["created_at"], date_parser=dateparse)
```

Shows the next error:
(After a long stack trace, the next end)

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _should_parse_dates(self, i)
    786             return self.parse_dates
    787         else:
--> 788             name = self.index_names[i]
    789             j = self.index_col[i]
    790 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Sample of my data
[image: The view of my data table]

I have no ideas how to handle it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give us a downloadable sample of some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the parameters you have are not necessary. Pandas, at least for me (0.15.2), has no problem interpreting dates in your sample data, while your function actually fails on some of them because of the +XX:XX portion.

The following works with your data for me:

```
df_f = pd.read_csv("my_out1.csv", parse_dates=['created_at'])
```

This will let you do expected sorts of things with dates, eg:

```
df_f[(df_f.created_at>'2011-01') & (df_f.created_at<'2012-01')]
```

Note too that the header argument you have is also wrong: header is zero-indexed, so should be 0 if you use it with your data.

Also, it looks like you're using an iPython notebook, and your example data has what appear to be utf-8 characters. You'll want to run the following to make sure your data can be displayed:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

This works to build a dataframe based on the sample you've given us:

```
df_f = pd.read_csv('my_out1.csv')
```

Comment: ValueError: 'created_at' is not in list

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: This story started, because I want to group by ["created_at"] year and month, but "'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'", so I must somehow to convert

Comment: The format I want is (datetype)("2014-10-05 08:20:48")

Comment: @cge's answer does that perfectly.